# Is it possible to use a dynamic file name for an ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to use dynamic filenames within an ng-include?  It doesn't look like this is possible so any alternatives would be very welcome.  I have a list of icons to display in different circumstances and I don't fancy a lot of `if` statements.

Something like this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div ng-include="{{file.name}}"></div>
```

Is this the only possible way to do it?:

```
 <ng-include src="file.name"> </ng-include>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/advice.

Comment: You can use <img ng-src="filepath"></img>, Or you can create a css class for each icon with background image set, use ng-class for the image. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the second code sample is the only way to do it.  Why do you want to do it another way?

Comment: Yeah I thought so, I'm trying to load an svg file based on the file name.  So if {{file.name}} equates to '100.svg' then it would load '100.svg'.

Comment: Problem solved, wasn't an issue with the `include` it was to do with the content in the svg file I was provided - how annoying.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` is dynamic:

```
<button ng-click="template = 'temp1.html'">Temp1.html</button>
<button ng-click="template = 'temp2.html'">Temp2.html</button>

<div ng-include="template"></div>
```